# In-App purchase is showing different currency symbol for some countries

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, skproduct

This is my code for getting the local price and currency symbol.

```
private func getLocalCurrencyAndPrice(from product: SKProduct) -> (currency: String, price: Double) {
    //Get the currency
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    numberFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale
    let priceString = numberFormatter.string(from: 0)
    let currencyString = ((priceString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "0", with: ""))?.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ""))?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
    let trimmedCurrency = currencyString?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    
    //Get the price
    let price = (product.price.doubleValue).roundToDecimal(2)
    return (currency: trimmedCurrency ?? "", price: price)
}
```

And this is how I am getting separate values:

```
let currency = getLocalCurrencyAndPrice(from: product).currency
let price = getLocalCurrencyAndPrice(from: product).price
```

I have created sandbox users for different App Store regions from the App Store Connect. It shows almost all regional prices and currency symbols perfectly except for **Indonesia, Taiwan & Korea**.

**For Indonesia**, on the "App Store Connect" It is showing `Rp` as their currency symbol:
(Please ignore the differences in currency amount for now for all 3 countries)

[image]

But on the application, it is showing `IDR`:

[image]

**For Taiwan**, on the "App Store Connect" & on the application, It is showing `$` as their currency symbol:

[image]

But on the "Settings > App Store > Sandbox User > Manage" & "Purchase Pop-Up view", it is showing `NT$` as their currency symbol:

[image]

**For Korea**, on the "App Store Connect", "Settings > App Store > Sandbox User > Manage" & "Purchase Pop-Up view", It is showing `₩` as their currency symbol:

[image]

But on the application, it is showing `₩` with a double line:

[image]

Why these mismatches are showing while I am getting the value from the same source? What have I done wrongly?

Comment: Because one is a web site with a particular localisation and the other is your app with iOS number formatters localisation

Comment: @Paulw11 Is there any way that exists to mitigate it? There's nothing I found besides using `numberFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale` to get the local symbol. Thanks for commenting :)

Comment: I don't see that there is really anything to mitigate. The localisation on the two platforms is different that is all. I am sure people in those countries will understand the pricing

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code. It has the solution of your specific problems i.e. for Indonesia, Taiwan and Korea, the method will return expected currency code. However this method has also some issue with currency code for some other countries like Pakistan.

```
func getSymbolForCurrencyCode(code: String) -> String {
    var candidates: [String] = []
    let locales: [String] = NSLocale.availableLocaleIdentifiers
    for localeID in locales {
        guard let symbol = findMatchingSymbol(localeID: localeID, currencyCode: code) else {
            continue
        }
        if symbol.count == 1 {
            return symbol
        }
        candidates.append(symbol)
    }
    return candidates[0]
}

func findMatchingSymbol(localeID: String, currencyCode: String) -> String? {
    let locale = Locale(identifier: localeID as String)
    if code != currencyCode {
        return nil
    }
    guard let symbol = locale.currencySymbol else {
        return nil


    }
    return symbol
}
```

Usage

let idr = getSymbolForCurrencyCode(code: "IDR")